# AppleScript copy and paste file with right-click

Tags: applescript, copy-paste

Sorry I don't have more of a foundation but I know nothing of AppleScript. Basically I want to right-click on a file or folder and run a script that will copy it to a new location with a constant directory structure. So obviously the scripting is way off, but something like this..

path = /Volumes/RENDERS/ThisShow/ThisShot/ThisShow_ThisShot_v10/

newPath = from 'path' ReplaceText("/Volumes/RENDERS/" ,  "/Volumes/Raid-Renders/")

tell application "Finder" to duplicate file 'path' to 'newPath' with replacing

In this example "path" would be the file or folder that was right clicked on when launching the script. The new folder in this example would be "/Volumes/Raid-Renders/ThisShow/ThisShot/ThisShow_ThisShot_v10/". So the idea is that it would copy "ThisShow_ThisShot_v10" folder and its content to "/Volumes/Raid-Renders/ThisShow/ThisShot/"

Thanks for any help. I know there isn't a lot to go on here.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
set thisFolder to the POSIX path of (choose file)
set the destinationFolder to (replaceText(thisFolder) as POSIX file as alias)
tell application "Finder" to duplicate (thisFolder as POSIX file as alias) to the destinationFolder with replacing

on replaceText(this_folder)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "RENDERS"
    set these_items to every text item of this_folder
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "Raid-Renders"
    return these_items as string
end replaceText
```

As far as I know, you can't assign an AppleScript to a right-click menu. However, you *can* create a menu bar script. To do this, first save this script as a regular script file in the `Scripts` folder of the local `Library` folder.

If you have a little icon in your main menubar (located at the top of the screen) that looks like a scroll (formerly known as the `Script Menu`), the script should appear somewhere in that menu. If you don't see the icon, run `AppleScript Utility` (located at `/Applications/AppleScript/AppleScript Utility`) and check the `Show Script Menu in menu bar` checkbox.

Now, all you have to do to run the script is open up the Script Menu, find your script, and just click on it once. Questions? Ask. :)

Comment: Thanks, This is helpful but instead of choosing the destination folder could I have it set the destination folder automatically  by doing a text replacement? in other word this script will ALWAYS copy from "/Volumes/RENDERS/" to "/Volumes/Raid-Renders/" with the rest of the file path left the same.

Comment: this is close. it works but only if the folder I would want to replace is already there. otherwise I get "Can't make file ... into alias." Also it only seems to work on folders. If I try to use it on a file I get "Can't make alias ... into type folder"   PS on the "replaceText" portion I changed "this_folder" to "thisFolder" like the first line of the code. Let me know if that was the wrong thing to do.  Thanks!

Comment: @lacrossj See updated answer. Also, you wanted to duplicate all the files in the folder.

Comment: This seems a good time to mention [FastScripts](http://www.red-sweater.com/fastscripts/), which is just so much nicer than the built-in script menu. And it's free, unless you want to add more than 10 keyboard shortcuts. (No affiliation, by the way; I just like FastScripts)